# php executing code from previous version of file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie using phpmyAdmin on a NAS drive.  I have a simple html page which calls a php file (CommitteeExtract.php) to retrieve data from a mySQL database on the server.  While developing I created a number of versions of the php file.  I eventually got it working on version 8 (CommitteeExtract8.php).  I now want to rename it to CommitteeExtract.php.  However, when I do so the generated html file looks and works like the original (failed) verison.  I have noticed renaming the file to any previous version give the result from that version, even if the code in the file is version 8.

Is the server caching the old versions and ignoring the current content?  How do I get it to recognise only the current version.

I hope this is clear, any help would be appreciated:

CommitteeExtract.php looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style_Main.css" >
    <title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Street</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>MobilePhone</th>
        </tr>

        <?php

            $servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xxx";
            $username = "User";
            $password = "1234";
            $dbase = "mydatabase";

            // Create connection
            $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Cannot ccnnect to server");
            mysql_select_db($dbase) or die("Could not connect to $dbase database");
            clearstatcache();
            $query="SELECT FullName, DateOfBirth, EmailAddress, Street, Town, City, County, PostCode, MobilePhone FROM mydatabase'";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query Data Extract failed");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['FullName'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["DateOfBirth"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["EmailAddress"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["Street"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["Town"] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["MobilePhone"] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            mysql_free_result($result);mysql_close($link);
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
<p>There's a button down here! Waheyyyy</p>
<button type="Button" onclick="ExportToExcel()">Export to Excel</button>
</html>
```

it is called from a menu item in a list by this

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Export Data</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Gmail Contacts</a>
        <a href="CommitteeExtract.php" target="_blank">Committee Extract</a>
        <a href="#" onclick="ExportForms()">Produce Forms</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

When the href contains CommitteeExtract8.php, and the file is called CommitteeExtract8.php it works fine, returning my data.

However If rename the file to CommitteeExtract.php and change the href to CommitteeExtract.php it fails with same errors as the original CommitteeExtract.php, even though the code is completely different.

I'm sorry, I don't know how to view and post logs

Comment: Could you post your code, relevant config files and logs? This will make it easier for us to track down your problem.

Comment: guessing - apologies if this is stating the obvious -  I assume you renamed the original file to something else first. You cannot rename a file to something that already exists - you will get an error. You could delete the original version first and then rename version 8. Or copy version8 to the original name but you will then get a prompt asking if you want to overwrite it.

Comment: That's what I did I have deleted all the old versions and renamed number CommitteeExtract8.phpto CommitteeExtract.php.  But it seems to still look at the old CommitteeExtract.php, which has been deleted